# Defining table schema programmatically with nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-bigquery

I'm trying to define create a table in an automatic manner using nodejs "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^3.0.0" in the following way:

```js
    const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
    schema = `driverId:string, passengerIds:(repeated string), pickedUp:(repeated string), createdat: integer, id:string, point:geography`;
    try {
            const table = await bigqueryClient.dataset(DATASET).table(tableName);
            const insertOptions: InsertRowsOptions = {
                autoCreate: true,
                schema: schema,
             }
            const response: InsertRowsResponse = await table.insert(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(document)), insertOptions);
            console.log(`insert completed: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        }
        catch(err) {
            // An API error or partial failure occurred.
            console.error(`failed to insert: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        }
```

The thing is that if I use primitive types, there is no problem, but I'm struggling to find out how I do have to properly declare repeatable types and also with record kind of types. Anyone could give me some guidance about how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally found out how to do it, just pass the schema as an object defined in the way it is done in the python example will do the trick for instance:

```
 schema = [
    {
        "name": "driverId",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "passengerIds",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REPEATED"
    },
    {
        "name": "pickedUp",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REPEATED"
    },
    {
        "name": "createdat",
        "type": "integer",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "POINT",
        "type": "GEOGRAPHY",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
]
```